# Como converter uma data que está em formato de string no banco na hora de fazer uma query?

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu tenho uma data que está em formato de string no banco `"dd/MM/yyyy"` e eu precisava retornar na minha query as datas a partir do dia de hoje. Como eu posso fazer essa conversão na query para comparar com o dia de hoje? Agradeço desde já!

atualização: Estou usando o comando `minha_data > date('now')` tenho 3 datas no meu banco 2/7/2015, 3/12/2015 e 3/3/2016, mas está retornando apenas a ultima data, deveria retornar as 2 ultimas.

Comment: Tem certeza que `date('now')` está no formato **dd/mm/yyyy**? Ele pode estar em **mm/dd/yyyy**.

Comment: sim, eu gravei neste formato, e quando retorno está assim também.

Answer (score 1):

É bem provável que o resultado de `date('now')` não venha no formato **dd/mm/yyyy** (o padrão é **yyyy/mm/dd**).

Você pode aplicar uma formatação com `strftime()` para que o retorno de `date()` seja no formato que suas datas estão salvas.

```
minha_data > strftime('%d/%m/%Y', date('now'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Em php use:

```
echo date('d/m/Y')
```

Outra questão, porque você está usando no formato local? Isso ta configurado no banco? Geralmente campos de data em banco de dados usam o tipo do campo DATE, isso vai lhe proporcionar a possibilidade de comparação de intervalos de datas, se seu campo está como VARCHAR provavelmente está errado ou seu uso é específico para isso.

Comment: O que a pergunta tem a ver com PHP?

Comment: Realmente, não notei a linguagem, desculpas.

Comment: Capaz, acontece =)